# Meaning of 'Default Database' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was going through the specifications for loading data into and from MySQL tables at [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), when I came across the specifications for the `local` option in the `load infile data` command. It says that if `local` is not used, then **if a file name with no leading components is given, the server looks for the file in the database directory of the default database**. Can anyone tell me what is meant by **default database** here, and how to set one? Can it be set from within MySQL itself, or through some server directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default database is the one you called with a `USE` clause or specified at login time. If you use `SELECT * FROM tablename` as opposed to `SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename` you also use the default database.

**Edit**

Just to make that clear: The default database is not a static thing - it is defined only for a defined point in time on a defined session - e.g. such as the PIT and session where you start the `load data infile` command.

Comment: Then, as per the answer above, if `use` specifies one database, and the directive specifies another, which one will have priority?

Comment: The one in the [client] section will be chosen on connect - any USE statement later (or any override in the client connection) will change it. Different points in time, different default DBs

Answer (score 1):

Generally the default database will be specified in a `database` param under the `[client]` header in your config (my.ini/my.cnf/etc), like such:

```
[client] 
database = name_of_default_db
```

Comment: Yes. It is a server directive, that is specified in your config.

Comment: So does that mean when PHP starts a session it doesn't need to issue a command like `use foo`, any query will look for tables in the default database `foo`?